# Call a function when a button is clicked in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, swiftui

I have switched from developing an app from Obj-C to swiftUI.
I have a button, when clicked on it should show popupview. Followed this link to display popup https://blog.techchee.com/how-to-create-a-pop-up-view-with-swiftui/

But popup doesn't show up when clicked on the button. Here's my code

```
struct Location: View {
var body: some View {
   ZStack{
           Button(action: {
                popUpView()
           

        }, label: {
            Text("Select Location")
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: 500)
                .padding()
                .background(Color.clear)
                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                .font(.custom("Open Sans", size: 18))
                .overlay(
                          RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                           .stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 2)
                                )
        })
       



}
}

private let choices = ["Apple", "Orange", "Papaya", "Grape", "Star Fruit", "Strawberries", "Raspberries", "Blueberries"].sorted()

   
    func popUpView()-> some View  {
        
      
        VStack (spacing : 10) {
              Text("Choices Of Fruits").font(Font.custom("Avenir-Black", size: 18.0))
                .position(x:100 , y:400)
                  List(choices, id:\.self) { Text($0) }
                  Button(action: {
                      withAnimation {

                       }
                   }, label: {
                           Text("Close")
                   })
           
           }
               .padding()
               .frame(width: 240, height: 300)
               .background(Color.white)
               .cornerRadius(20)
               .shadow(radius: 20 )

    }
    
}
```

Plz help in where am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your design, you can just add conditions within the main ZStack and hide show the view.
Also, you can use the sheet.

```
struct Location: View {
    @State private var isPresent: Bool = false // <-- Here
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation {
                    isPresent = true // <-- Here
                }
                
            }, label: {
                Text("Select Location")
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: 500)
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.clear)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                    .font(.custom("Open Sans", size: 18))
                    .overlay(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                            .stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 2)
                    )
            })
            
            if isPresent { // <-- Here
                popUpView()
            }
        }
    }
    
    private let choices = ["Apple", "Orange", "Papaya", "Grape", "Star Fruit", "Strawberries", "Raspberries", "Blueberries"].sorted()
    
    
    func popUpView()-> some View  {
        
        
        VStack (spacing : 10) {
            Text("Choices Of Fruits").font(Font.custom("Avenir-Black", size: 18.0))
                .position(x:100 , y:400)
            List(choices, id:\.self) { Text($0) }
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation {
                    isPresent = false // <-- Here
                }
            }, label: {
                Text("Close")
            })
            
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(width: 240, height: 300)
        .background(Color.white)
        .cornerRadius(20)
        .shadow(radius: 20 )
        
    }
    
}
```